# How To Reference a container from a button on same level in ExtJS

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I've got a structure like below.

I can reference (from the button handler) with up.down my component but I'm wondering if there is a more correct way to do this.

```
   Ext.application({
        name: 'MyApp',
        launch: function () {
            Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
                items: [
                    {
                        tpl: 'Name: {first} {last}',
                        data: {
                            first: 'Peter',
                            last: 'Kellner'
                        },
                        padding: 20,
                        width: 200,
                        height: 200,
                        style: {
                            border: '2px solid red'
                        },
                        resizable: true,
                        itemId: 'myComponentItemId',
                        listener: {
                            resize: {
                                fn: function(component, width, height) {
                                    console.log("w/h:" + width + " " + height);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },{
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: "Disable",
                        handler: function () {
                            debugger;
                            this.up().down('#myComponentItemId').disable();
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think that is an okay way of doing it. However, i usually specify where i'm going 'up' to in case I nest the button deeper, etc. ie. `btn.up('form')`  If you need to find a component from controller, sometimes I'll use `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#itemId')[0]`

Comment: I'm trying to avoid componentQuery since it is the full scope of the app. It seems like there should be some simple way to get a sister node I'm not seeing.  thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

It is correct to use `.up.down` for what you are trying to do. You could use something like :

```
.up('form').down('button#login')
```

What you use in your code, on the other hand is not correct : `this.up().down('#myComponentItemId')`. You must pass a component selector as argument to `.up()`.

Alternatives to `.up.down` are [`.nextSibling`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-nextSibling) and [`.previousSibling`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-previousSibling). Similar, but more general there are also [`.nextNode`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-nextNode) and [`.previousNode`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-previousNode).

Comment: Not entirely true. `up` without args will just get the container.

Comment: Evan, you are everywheres! I was giving the sencha forums a little rest from me.  But, while you are here, what is a better way to get a container that is on the same level as my button I am pressing?

Comment: While it is optional to add arg to up(), it is best practice to do so.. the code will have less chance of breaking if you are moving your components around/(refactoring).